# Is there any way to break the while statement out of a loop and then bring it back so that WPF can update the UI in real time?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a C# script that I am writing to try to update a UI in real-time in order to count up to a number that is specified by the user. This is what I have so far:

```
namespace WpfApp4
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public string respond
        {
            get
            {
                return response.Text;
            }
            set
            {
                response.Text = value;
            }
        }
        private void confirm_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            int repeat1 = 0;
            int repeat = Int32.Parse(respond);
            while (repeat1 <= repeat)
            {
                this.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
                {
                    number1.Text = repeat1.ToString();
                });
                repeat1++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The part that I need to break from and then come back to without any `do-while`, or `while` statements is the `while (repeat1 <= repeat)` loop. Here is the xaml code that goes with the C# script:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp4.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp4"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <TextBlock Text="Enter a number:" Margin="145,189,274,102" />
        <TextBox x:Name="response" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" Margin="254,189,0,0"/>
        <Button x:Name="confirm" Content="Submit" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="52" Margin="164,223,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="210" Click="confirm_Click"/>
        <TextBlock x:Name="number1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="145,67,0,0" Height="91" Width="229"/>
        <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="108" Margin="140,62,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="241"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

When I enter a number everything does exactly what it should, but because the C# script is stuck in a loop, WPF cannot update the UI until it reaches the number that is entered by the user, which is not what I want as I am trying to get it to update in real-time in a similar fashion to this code snippet:

```
static void Bat(int m)
        {
            int repeat = 0;
            do
            {
                Console.WriteLine(repeat);
                repeat++;
            }
            while (repeat <= 1000000);
            if(repeat >= 1000001)
            {
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
```

However, unlike this snippet, it is not being ran in a console and I don't want the app to write out each number on an individual line, I just want it to update the text block with the most recent number calculated by the C# script. If anyone can help, it would be greatly appreciated.

Edit: Simplified the code snippet

Comment: The click handler inclusive the loop is executed in the UI thread -- effectively blocking the UI thread until the loop is finished. Solution: Let the whole loop execute on a background thread (or use some form of async/Task programming). Side note: you will still not see the effect as in a console application, as the UI updates will happen so fast that most probably you will only see the last value in the number1 textbox (and perhaps brief flashes of a few intermediate values as well)

Answer (score 1):

The short version: you're doing it all wrong.

Your code has two major problems with it:

1. You are executing your loop in the UI thread. This blocks the UI thread from doing anything while it works.
    Oddly enough, you include a call to `Dispatcher.Invoke()`, which suggests that you made some effort to investigate moving the loop to another thread, but failed to completely understand what you found. In your code, the call to `Invoke()` does nothing useful, because you're already in the UI thread when you call it.
2. You are accessing UI elements directly, instead of using a view model data structure to separate your main program logic from the UI presentation of that logic.

You also have a couple of minor issues. Not fatal, but certainly unconventional and likely will impede your ability to write good WPF programs going forward:

3. You attach an event handler directly to the `Button.Click` event, instead of implementing `ICommand`. This is related to the lack of use of a view model, as one much more often finds `ICommand` implementations in a view model.
4. You have no delay in your counting. No matter what your implementation, this is likely to overwhelm the UI thread with updates, as your computer can increase a simple counter orders of magnitude more quickly than the UI can be made to present the counter's value to the user, as well as than the user themselves could possibly read it.

There are a number of good examples of how to address each of these questions, already on Stack Overflow and elsewhere. But, I wasn't able to find a question that I think would do a good job addressing both questions at the same time. So I will attempt to do so here.

All of the issues above are relatively simple to address:

1. To fix the first issue, in the past, the only way to address this would be to run the operation in a background/worker thread. This approach actually still works quite well in WPF, **if** you are using a view model and data binding, because WPF automatically will handle cross-thread updates to properties that are bound to UI elements. That is, when the property value changes in other than the UI thread, it will handle the binding target update in the UI thread.
   In modern C#, an even better way to approach a simple scenario like this is to code the loop in an `async` method, using some mechanism like `await Task.Delay()` to provide a way for the loop to yield control and let the UI update.
   In my example below, I have demonstrated both of these approaches.
2. To fix the second issue, just use the expected WPF paradigm of view model and data binding. See e.g. "MVVM", a broad term for the general concept as used in WPF and other XAML-based APIs. At its core, this involves simply creating a separate data structure that holds the values you want to present to the user, and which implements the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface, so that when those values change, WPF is notified and can update the UI. WPF has extensive support for binding the most common data types, and for scenarios where that support doesn't suffice it provides other mechanisms to give you complete control over the binding. Done correctly, you will practically never need to directly access the property of a UI element from code-behind. Note that in my example below, I did not share the **MainWindow.xaml.cs** file. That's because I didn't have to do *anything* to that file. It's just the stock template file, with no changes done by me.
3. The third issue is addressed by implementing `ICommand` and providing properties in the view model for your commands. Of course, the first step in this is to have a view model. An optional step that makes it a lot easier is to use a class like my `DelegateCommand` shown below, to provide an `ICommand` implementation that uses methods from your view model or other data structures to provide the actual implementation details. (My example here is just the minimal implementation I needed for this example; in practice, I use a version with more features. Many other people have also written similar classes; they are most commonly named `DelegateCommand` or `RelayCommand`, and you can learn a lot by searching the web for examples of those.)
4. The fourth issue can be addressed a couple of ways. I chose the simplest, which is to delay the actual counting to allow time for the UI and user to keep up. If you want the counting to go full speed, you'll want to do the counting using a variable separate from your view model property which is bound to the UI, and only update the view model property periodically, based on some type of timing mechanism (e.g. `Stopwatch` or `DateTime.UtcNow`). I recommend updating the UI no more frequently than once every 100 ms, but if you insist you can probably get away with updates as frequently as every 10 ms without breaking things, depending on the updates and how fast your computer is.

A final note on the updating: you might notice that the "foreground" counting updates the displayed value smoothly, while the "background" counting does not (it sort of halts and skips). This is a consequence of how the updating occurs. In the "foreground" version, the timing interval between updates is managed (implicitly) using a timer thread, but the visual update is done directly in the UI thread (by virtue of the `async`/`await`, which allows the loop to come back to the UI thread to perform the property value update).

This provides the best responsiveness for UI updates. In the "background" version, both the timing and the bound property update are done in the background thread. WPF schedules updates for the UI based on the bound property value using an asynchronous invocation on the `Dispatcher` object. This invocation is subject to more thread scheduling variability, because unlike in the "foreground" version, the UI isn't updated immediately when the bound property value itself is modified.

So, without further ado, here's how I would have written your program:

Basic `ICommand` implementation for reuse by the view model:

```
class DelegateCommand : ICommand
{
    private readonly Action _action;
    private readonly Func<bool> _canExecute;

    public DelegateCommand(Action action, Func<bool> canExecute)
    {
        _action = action;
        _canExecute = canExecute;
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return _canExecute();
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        _action();
    }

    public void RaiseCanExecuteChanged()
    {
        CanExecuteChanged?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
}
```

The view model class (this one implements `INotifyPropertyChanged` directly, but it is very common to put the event and helper method into a base class for reuse by all your view model classes):

```
class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private int _maxValue;
    private int _currentValue;
    private int? _taskThreadId;
    private bool _taskRunning;

    public ICommand StartInForeground { get; }
    public ICommand StartInBackground { get; }

    public int MaxValue
    {
        get { return _maxValue; }
        set { _UpdateField(ref _maxValue, value); }
    }

    public int CurrentValue
    {
        get { return _currentValue; }
        set { _UpdateField(ref _currentValue, value); }
    }

    public int? TaskThreadId
    {
        get { return _taskThreadId; }
        set { _UpdateField(ref _taskThreadId, value); }
    }

    public bool TaskRunning
    {
        get { return _taskRunning; }
        set { _UpdateField(ref _taskRunning, value, _OnTaskRunningChanged); }
    }

    public int UiThreadId { get; }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public ViewModel()
    {
        UiThreadId = Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId;
        StartInForeground = new DelegateCommand(_StartInForeground, () => !TaskRunning);
        StartInBackground = new DelegateCommand(_StartInBackground, () => !TaskRunning);
    }

    // NOTE: generally, "async void" methods should be avoided. They are legitimate
    // for event handlers and, as in this case, invoked commands and for illustration
    // purposes.
    private async void _StartInForeground()
    {
        TaskRunning = true;
        await _CountUp();
        TaskRunning = false;
    }

    private async void _StartInBackground()
    {
        TaskRunning = true;
        await Task.Run(_CountUp);
        TaskRunning = false;
    }

    private async Task _CountUp()
    {
        TaskThreadId = Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId;
        CurrentValue = 0;
        while (CurrentValue < MaxValue)
        {
            await Task.Delay(100);
            CurrentValue++;
        }
        TaskThreadId = null;
    }

    private void _OnTaskRunningChanged(bool obj)
    {
        // NOTE: this method is _not_ automatically marshalled to the UI thread
        // by WPF, because its execution doesn't go through a binding. So it's
        // important that the TaskRunning property is only modified in the UI
        // thread. An alternative implementation would do additional work to
        // capture the current SynchronizatioContext when this ViewModel object
        // is created and use it to post the method calls below.
        ((DelegateCommand)StartInForeground).RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
        ((DelegateCommand)StartInBackground).RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
    }

    protected void _UpdateField<T>(ref T field, T newValue,
        Action<T> onChangedCallback = null,
        [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        if (EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(field, newValue))
        {
            return;
        }

        T oldValue = field;

        field = newValue;
        onChangedCallback?.Invoke(oldValue);
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

And the XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="TestSO44333293WpfCountup.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:l="clr-namespace:TestSO44333293WpfCountup"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
  <Window.DataContext>
    <l:ViewModel/>
  </Window.DataContext>

  <StackPanel>
    <Grid>
      <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
      </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <TextBlock Text="Enter maximum value: "/>
      <TextBox Text="{Binding MaxValue}" Grid.Column="1"/>
      <Button Content="Start In Foreground" Command="{Binding StartInForeground}" Grid.Column="2"/>
      <Button Content="Start In Background" Command="{Binding StartInBackground}" Grid.Column="3"/>
    </Grid>
    <UniformGrid Columns="3">
      <TextBlock Text="{Binding CurrentValue, StringFormat=Current Value: {0}}"/>
      <TextBlock Text="{Binding UiThreadId, StringFormat=UI Thread Id: {0}}"/>
      <TextBlock Text="{Binding TaskThreadId, StringFormat=Task Thread Id: {0}}"/>
    </UniformGrid>
  </StackPanel>
</Window>
```